# Laravel 5.4 mail markdown 2 button inline

Tags: laravel, email, markdown

I would like to know how to place the button next to each other.

[image]

Now it is on a separate line.

```
@component('mail::message')
    Dear {{$vendor_name}}

    Product {{$product_id}} : {{$product_name}} price id : {{$price_id}} will expire on {{$date_expire}}.
    Please renew price.


@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://phuketjettour.com/', 'color' => 'green'])
    Phuket Jet Tour
@endcomponent
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://phuketjettour.com/s/vendors'])
    Vendor submission
@endcomponent
    Thanks,<br>
    Phuket Jet Tour

@endcomponent
```

Comment: please post yout email blade  or the code where you configure this button

Comment: @Dearwolves i update blade in post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Dynamic number of inline buttons

For me the following worked to create 2, 3, 4 (dynamic number) of buttons inline in Laravel markdown mails:

[image: 3 inline buttons without headline]

### 1) Add a new directory for your custom component

First lets extend the mail configuration to include our new directory for components:

**config/mail.php**

```
<?php 

// ...

'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        resource_path('views/emails/components') // <-- This line was added
    ],
],
```

### 2) Create the new component for inline buttons

You need to create both, the HTML and the text version of the component. Otherwise you will get a **InvalidArgumentException** "View $name not found":

**www/resources/views/emails/components/html/buttons.blade.php**

This is the **HTML** file:

```
<table class="action" align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
@if(null !== ($headline ?? null))
<tr><td><h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ $headline }}</h2></td></tr>
@endif
<tr>
<td>
@foreach($buttons as $button)
<a href="{{ $button['url'] }}" class="button button-{{ $button['color'] ?? 'primary' }}" target="_blank" rel="noopener">{!! $button['slot'] !!}</a>
@endforeach
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**www/resources/views/emails/components/text/buttons.blade.php**

This is the **text** file

```
@if(null !== ($headline ?? null))
{{ $headline }}
------------------------------
@endif
@foreach($buttons as $button)
{!! $button['slot'] !!}: {{ $button['url'] }}
@endforeach
```

### 3) Include the new component in your mails:

Now you can just include the component in your markdown emails like so:

**Example with *2 inline buttons* and a *headline*:**

[image: 2 inline buttons with headline]

```
@component('mail::buttons', [
    'headline' => 'Share link',
    'buttons' => [
        [
            'url' => 'https://wa.me/?text=' . urlencode('Whatsapp text'),
            'slot' => 'WhatsApp',
        ],[
            'url' => 'https://t.me/share/url?text=' . urlencode('telegram text'),
            'slot' => 'Telegram',
        ]
    ]
])
@endcomponent
```

**Example with *3 inline buttons* *without* a headline:**

[image: 3 inline buttons without headline]

```
@component('mail::buttons', [
    'buttons' => [
        [
            'url' => 'https://wa.me/?text=' . urlencode('Whatsapp text'),
            'slot' => 'WhatsApp',
        ],[
            'url' => 'https://t.me/share/url?text=' . urlencode('telegram text'),
            'slot' => 'Telegram',
        ],[
            'url' => 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' . urlencode('Twitter text'),
            'slot' => 'Twitter',
        ]
    ]
])
@endcomponent
```

**Example with *3 inline buttons* with different *colours*:**

[image: 3 inline buttons with different colours]

```
@component('mail::buttons', [
    'buttons' => [
        [
            'url' => 'https://wa.me/?text=' . urlencode('Whatsapp text'),
            'slot' => 'WhatsApp',
            'color' => 'blue' // This is the default
        ],[
            'url' => 'https://t.me/share/url?text=' . urlencode('telegram text'),
            'slot' => 'Telegram',
            'color' => 'green'
        ],[
            'url' => 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' . urlencode('Twitter text'),
            'slot' => 'Twitter',
            'color' => 'red'
        ]
    ]
])
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Sorry for the late accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it like this, ofcourse the css should be in a separated file

```
<style>
    .email-row {
    }
    .email-col-2 {
        width: 49%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

@component('mail::message')
<div class="email-row">
    <div class="email-col-2">
        @component('mail::button', ['url' => '453634', 'color' => 'light'])
            btn1
        @endcomponent
    </div>
    <div class="email-col-2">
        @component('mail::button', ['url' => '123', 'color' => 'green'])
            bnt2
        @endcomponent
    </div>
</div>

@endcomponent
```

Answer (score 1):

When passing a variable to a blade template, use a single quote ( ' ) instead of a double quote ( " ).

```
$btn_style = " color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #FEFEFE; padding: 5px 30px;";    
$buttons = '<span style="text-align: center; width: 100%; display: inline-block;">
                <a href="'. url('/login') .'" style="background: #449a44; '.$btn_style.'"> Accept </a>
                <a href="'. url('/some/url/'. $id) .'" style="background: #b76161; '.$btn_style.'"> Decline </a>
            </span>';
```

To render this code:

Edit your **App\Mail**

```
$this
    ->subject('Subject')
    ->markdown('emails.tempalte')
    ->with([
      'buttons' => $buttons,
    ]);
```

Blade Template **view\emails**:

```
{!! $buttons !!}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can put it in one `<div>`
For example:

```
<div class = "row>
```

your buttons here

```
</div>
```

If it doesn't help please share your code

---

Try this:

```
<span style="display: inline;">

@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://phuketjettour.com/', 'color' => 'green'])
    Phuket Jet Tour
@endcomponent
@component('mail::button', ['url' => 'http://phuketjettour.com/s/vendors'])
    Vendor submission
@endcomponent

</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just a work around. I've inspect the email from a laravel project.

try this in place of your component for button :

```
<a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-green"> Phuket Jet Tour</a>
<a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-blue">SAMPLE !</a>
```

it inlines your button. then just adjust other element. If you want to put the button on the markdown then you do like:

On your markdown:

```
$button1= "   <a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-green"> Phuket Jet Tour</a>";
$button2 = "<a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-blue">SAMPLE !</a>";

  $emailMarkdown = $this->markdown('your_email_template')
                ->subject('your_subject)
                //you will define here the variables you need to pass in the template
                ->with([    
                   'emailBody' => $emailBody,
                   'button_first' => $button1,
                   'button_second' => $button2,
                ]);

     return $emailMarkdown;
```

then on the email template:

```
@component('mail::message')
        Dear {{$vendor_name}}

        Product {{$product_id}} : {{$product_name}} price id : {{$price_id}} will expire on {{$date_expire}}.
        Please renew price.

    {!!$button_first!!} {!!$button_second!!}
@endcomponent
```

Comment: if use html in markdown. it change html to string 
Product 19361 : 2142352 price id : 2124284 will expire on 2018-12-27 00:00:00.
Please renew price.

<a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-green"> Phuket Jet Tour</a>
<a href = "http://phuketjettour.com/" class="button button-blue">SAMPLE !</a>

Comment: what i do there is you directly put the button on the email blade template.

Answer (score -1):

To fix the issue, just place this code in email blade file:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <a href="{{ $link }}" class="button button-red">Cancel</a>
  <a href="{{ $link }}" class="button button-blue">Reschedule</a>
  <a href="{{ $link }}" class="button button-green">Confirm</a>
</div>
```