# How to create new Laravel mail component(template) and use it in email blade file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have created a new file in **resources/views/vendor/mail/html/coupon.blade.php and in
resources/views/vendor/mail/markdown/coupon.blade.php**

also in config/mail.php, I changed the configuration to this.

```
'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
```

But still I am not able to use

```
@component('mail::coupon')
```

in my email blade file. its throwing following error.

```
Facade/Ignition/Exceptions/ViewException with message 'View [coupon] not found.
```

Comment: Did you try clearing the cache and restarting the server? It might not have picked up the change.

Comment: yes i did that also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Still, I am not able to use like `@component('mail::coupon')` but I find out workaround to use like this  `@component('vendor.mail.markdown.coupon')` to specify email template file.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and for me the issue was, that just the **component as text was missing**. Both files are required

So if you have:
resources/views/vendor/mail/**html**/coupon.blade.php

you also need:
resources/views/vendor/mail/**text**/coupon.blade.php

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68095965/936284 to check, how I created a new component `mail::buttons`

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
resources/views/mail/html/coupon.blade.php 

resources/views/mail/markdown/coupon.blade.php
```

skip vendor directory

Comment: did you read this?
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#markdown-mailables and 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail#writing-markdown-messages

Comment: also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42724118/laravel-5-4-how-to-customize-notification-email-layout